# Macbook Pro with SVGA splitter, only 1 of 2 external monitors is showing.

Tags: display, multiple-monitors, macbook-pro, projector

I've got a Macbook Pro set up for delivering trainings and speeches. In my setup I use the native display (which only I can see) to peek into the next slide, or to take notes. Then, the external display is used for showing whatever content I want the audience to look at. For that, I have original Apple adapters, in order to connect to most external monitors and projectors (Thunderbolt to SVGA display adapter and HDMI cables)

Now I want to have the External Display of the audience (which I can't see, because it's on my back) mirrored into a third monitor which I will place side by side at my notebook.

For that, I bought a SVGA Splitter. First I connect my Thunderbolt to SVGA display adapter into the Thunderbolt port. Then I connect the SVGA splitter into the out-port of this display port. After that, I connect the two external displays (the monitor and the project) into the two out-ports of the SVGA splitter.

At this moment, both external displays blink, indicating that they received some signal, but only the projector ever displays the output.

If connected alone, either of the external displays shows the output, which means they are working. However, I never managed to make them work together, even after trying to scale the second display (which is to be split) into different resolutions.

The only problem I can think of is that the external monitor and the projector have different native resolutions, so that only one of them gets to receive the correct image from the Macbook.

Am I missing something? Should I give you more information?

Comment: What resolutions do you have everything set at?  Have you tried making sure all displays are at the same resolution?

Comment: If I connect either of the external displays individually, I can make them to accept at least 800x600 and 1024x768. However, that doesn't happen when both are connected. Maybe it's just that the divided signal (when both are connected) doesn't have power enough to be recognized by the old display, but the projector is more sensible? I guess I'll never know.